# Node.js for Windows and Macs — forward slash, backslash rectification

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Is there a method to rectify the discrepancy in node.js from Windows to Linux and Mac concerning the backslash versus forward slash?

Windows requires backslashes when calling locations in `git bash`, while Mac/Linux requires forward slashes.  I'm working on a project with both Mac and Windows users so I can't change all the forward slashes to backslashes in the code because when Mac users pull, coffee wont be able to properly run for them and vice versa.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure to use [path](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html) methods instead of typing out paths. [`path.normalize()`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_p) and [`path.join()`](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) are particularly useful when developing cross platform:

On Windows:

```
$ node
> var p = require('path')
undefined
> p.normalize('/hey/there/you')
'\\hey\\there\\you'
> p.join('/hey', 'there', '/you')
'\\hey\\there\\you'
```

On Linux:

```
$ node
> var p = require('path')
undefined
> p.normalize('/hey/there/you')
'/hey/there/you'
> p.join('/hey', 'there', '/you')
'/hey/there/you'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Chad answer, when you are constructing paths you can:

```
var path = require("path");
"hey" + path.sep + "there" + path.sep + "you"
```

or

```
["hey", "there", "you"].join(path.sep);
```

Comment: This is what `path.join` does for you, but it also takes care to ensure you don't have double slashes and things as well.