# Not able to write data to a file in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I want to write text in an already created file in Node Js. Here is what I have done

Upload.html

```
<form enctype ="multipart/form-data" action ="/file" method ="post">


    MAC Address:<br>
  <input type="text" name="macadd" id="macadd"><br>

  Percentage:<br>
  <input type="text" name="percent" id="percent"><br>



<input type="submit"  value='Submit' id="upload">
<br>

</form>
```

App.js

```
app.route('/file').post(function (req,res,next) {

        var macadd =req.body.macadd;
       //var percent =req.body.percent;
        var path ="C:\Proj\doc\data.txt";
        var data ="hello";

        fs.writeFile(path,macadd , function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.error("write error:  " + error.message);
            } else {
                console.log("Successful Write to " + path);
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to write the value of 'macadd' into the file data.txt. It is mostly an integer value but when I click on submit, in the file it comes as 'undefined' even though it shows as successful write on the console. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added 2 slashes between the folders of the path and added the path-resolve package. Something like this:

`var path =resolve("C:\\Proj\\doc\\data.txt");`

For getting the values of the text box into the file I had to remove the encryption type in the form tag.

```
<form action ="/file" method ="post">


    MAC Address:<br>
  <input type="text" name="macadd" id="macadd"><br>

  Percentage:<br>
  <input type="text" name="percent" id="percent"><br>



<input type="submit"  value='Submit' id="upload">
<br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the way you specify the path:

`var path ="C:\Proj\doc\data.txt";`

should be:

`var path ="C:/Proj/doc/data.txt";`

Comment: I'm doing it on Windows. Is it necessary to still change the slashes?

Comment: It depends on if you want to be able to run on something other than Windows. If so, then use something like path normalize or resolve to make it portable. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364823/node-js-for-windows-and-macs-forward-slash-backslash-rectification) for further information

Answer (score 1):

You can use a node utility like `path-resolve` to help you here:

path-resolve: https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-resolve

```
$ npm install path-resolve --save
```

Then use as follows:

```
var resolve = require('path-resolve');
var path    = resolve("C:\Proj\doc\data.txt").replace(/\\/g,'/');
```

Comment: Still showing as successful write, but nothing in data.txt

Comment: Great! I'm trying to insert text field elements from an HTML page. It's coming as undefined in the data.txt. Any solutions?

Comment: @AmitNaik I think that is a different question. Perhaps mark the current question as resolved and create a new one.